# Can JS be used to check for and log temporary page changes by end users via dev tools or the console?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, code-inspection

The setup for this will be a Chrome instance on a VM I control (and thus can install anything I need onto it) for the purposes of monitoring changes to a web page that were not made by the web code itself. I will be testing a web site (on a Linux build, in Apache using a Tomcat or Jetty instance) which displays data from a backend database (I won't bore anyone with the details). That data once displayed can of course be edited by anyone who knows how to use dev tools and inspect element features in certain browsers, and while the changes made won't propagate back to the backend and can be wiped out with a refresh, I would like to monitor to see if those changes were nonetheless attempted.

I have already managed to find a way to monitor if the Dev Console has been opened using Chrome by using an extension that specifically hooks into its' toggle. Coupled with some JS code, I can then act upon when it is opened, closed or both, and for example, force a refresh of the page in the event that someone used the inspect element to make changes to the rendering of the page.

I would like to then check to see if any of the client-side elements have been altered, capture the changed values, and then retrieve the original data from the back-end to compare against (I can manage the back-end stuff). I've seen a few examples of the use of InnerText and InnerHTML as a means of checking, and will try it out later, but wanted to know if anyone had any experience with anything similar.

Comment: I suppose you could run a loop that verifies the code on the document is identical to the code in the back end using something like jquery.

Comment: Cool. So it is possible. Thanks. I'll experiment and figure out the best approach (and that'll probably be jquery like you said).